# Failed to enable constraints when filling datatable

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable

I am loading a data table from an XSD data set in C# in MSVS 2012.  The standard `GetData()` method runs properly.  However, my custom query `GetDataCustom()`, which returns only a few fields from the data set, throws the popular exception:

> Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values
>   violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

I used the Detailed Constraint Exception posted in reply to a similar issue here on SOV, which showed this detail:

```
Error filling table
No Row Errors reported in DataTable=[datatable_Custom]
```

I set `EnforceConstraints = false` on my data set, but the exceptions still were thrown.  I have looked through the many questions on SOV on this issue, but none of the other fixes helped.  What else can I try?

Edited to add code block:

```
ds_Sample dsSample = new ds_Sample();
dsSample.Clear();
dsSample.EnforceConstraints = false;
ds_SampleTableAdapters.ta_Sample taCustom = new ds_SampleTableAdapters.ta_Custom();
ds_Sample.dt_CustomDataTable dtCustom = taCustom.GetDataCustom();//throws exception
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it myself:  The table adapter had all the fields in the data set, but my query only had some of the fields in the table adapter.  I changed the table adapter to use the query of interest, and the problem was resolved.

Therefore, the constraint violation was most likely null data in `NOT NULL` fields.

Comment: could you please share a code how you made this work.

Comment: @JSB: It's been nine years, I no longer have access to the code.  I _think_ the constructor for the table adapter used a particular query, which was what needed changing.